# convergence of an infinite series of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

there is the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k^2+i)}{(k+i)^4}$.I wonder how it can be proved of convergence with ratio test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ratio test works the same way with real series as it does with complex. That is if  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} < 1$$ then the series converges. Unfortunately if the $a_k$'s are rational functions with respect to $k$, they will always return the indeterminant value $1$. You can try to demonstrate this yourself.

Note however that if a series converges absolutely then it converges. Further we can split this into two parts $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k+i)^4} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i}{(k+i)^4}$$ and $$\left| \frac{k^2}{(k+i)^4} \right| = \frac{|k|^2}{(|k|^2 + 1)^2}$$ and $$\left| \frac{i}{(k^2+i)^4} \right| = \frac{1}{(|k|^2 + 1)^2}$$
And both series converge absolutely by the traditional $p$-test. Thus the series converges absolutely and thus it converges.

Comment: There's a typo in your third equation : $|(k+i)^4|=(|k|^2 + 1)^2$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the comparison test: $$\frac{k^2+i}{(k+i)^4} = \frac{k^2}{k^4}\frac{1+\frac{i}{k^2}}{\left(1+\frac{i}{k}\right)^4} = \frac{1}{k^2}(1+o(1))$$

Comment: The comparison test is for series with only real positive terms. You can show the series converges absolutely with the comparison test, however.

Comment: Indeed... the line above is still true, but to apply the comparison theorem one has to take absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

No, the ratio test is inconclusive, the limit ratio being $1$.  However, [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test), which is an extension of the ratio test, does work and shows that the series converges absolutely.